# Integrating complex AngularJS web application with CMS?

Tags: angularjs, video, content-management-system

I've developed a web application using AngularJS that has some significant complexity to it. For example, a user can record a video through the web interface, which triggers a custom server process to analyze the video, which the front end then retrieves from the server and presents in a graph.

I've set up a video server (wowza) and created an angular directive to wrap the video player which plays RTMP video streams (a requirement is also that videos can only be played from specific IP addresses), as well as directives to wrap the video recorder and a service to interact with the server-side analysis code.

The client would ideally like the pages and videos to be managed through a CMS. I have no experience with CMS systems. Is this possible and how would I go about this?

Comment: Did you end up settling on a pre-built solution or roll your own?

Comment: I ended up creating a virtual machine set up with all the tools (Eclipse, git, etc) and called it a CMS,. The client seemed satisfied, and they've never touched it.

The truth is that I was (very arguably) contractually obligated to make a CMS, but the client was asking for a lot of functionality that could only be done with programming. It would have taken a lot of work to make a WYSIWYG editor capable of editing the content and that they could actually use.

Comment: I'm in the exact same boat. Currently looking into some extensible NodeJS CMS's that I might be able to bake my own custom functionality into.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few CMS systems specifically designed to work with Angular:

- http://respondcms.com
- https://github.com/jonniespratley/angular-cms

Many of the 'traditional' CMS solutions are multi page based as opposed to Angular's 'single page' architecture which can make integration a little tricky.

Its worth checking whatever approach you select has a believable migration path to Angular 2 also.

Answer (score 1):

You can go about this by creating a custom page on your chosen CMS framework that fetches the database for all liked pages and videos and returns them as json or xml object similar to a web service...

Then on your angularjs code you can create a service that fetches all liked pages and videos from the custom page that you have created using $http request and of course using that custom page's url...

```
factory('LikedItemsService', function($http, $q) {
  return {
    getLikedItems: function(loginData) {
      var q = $q.defer();
      $http({ 
        url:"http://mydomain/cms/api/custompage", //just a sample custom page url
        method:"POST",
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      }).then(function(resp) {       
          q.resolve(resp.data);
      }, function(err) {
          q.reject(err);
          console.log(err);
          alert('An unexpected error occured. Please try again later.');
      });

      return q.promise;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is definitely an approach that will work and that has been highlighted in blogs etc. One key issue with it is making the 'What you see is what you get' editor in the CMS system show and preview the site correctly. On many traditional CMS systems these WYSIWYG editors have the traditional multi page web paradigm strongly entrenched in their architecture.

Comment: I think for that, you just need to use the CMS for managing and editing the pages/videos ex. title, description, etc.. and have a separate page which will handle the fetching of the videos which in turn return a json or xml data..